# bootstrap a peer with a specific nodeId

Tags: peers

If you have node keys (generated using subey), is it possible to use them to boot a peer with the corresponding peerId?

is it possible to import the keys and thus have the same peerId **without using --node-key option when running the peer** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use your node executable.

```
./node -d foo --chain bar --node-key-file node-key
mv node-key foo/chains/bar/network/secret_ed25519
```

---

Actually, if you don't specify the `--node-key-file` the node will generate a `secret_ed25519` file under the network folder directly. You don't have to do anything.

Note: some old Substrate versions won't cache the node key file, the peer id will be changed every restart. IIRC, that is long long ago.

Comment: if we copy /network/secret_ed25519 from a peer to another one would it make the second peer boot with the first peer's id?

Comment: Yes. If you don't specify the `--node-key-file` or `--node-key`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible to have the same peerId without specifying it in your CLI execution as a hardcoded `--node-key`. In order to do that you must ensure that you have the `node-key` saved in your keystore in the respective location where the node key is stored.

There should be a default location for these type of key file on startup. You can generate a node-key to a file by following the description of section **subkey generate-node-key** in the [relevant Substrate Docs section](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/subkey/).